# Uploading phone's contact on server in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, server, android-volley

I am uploading my phone's contacts on the server in the background on button click. I am using volley for this purpose. The code is working fine for 500 contacts, but while uploading 1500 contacts the JSON gets breaked and it shows error 500. Any help on how to acheive this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a server side problem (Errorcode 500). You are probably running into post body's size limit on the server.

Comment: check the error on the server side, since it is a **server error**

Comment: thanks for your response. you are right its server side error and server is not storing long string

Answer (score 0):

You can write JSON into the file and after that load data with InputStream from file onto the server side.